# Why do I get an undefined function error when importing into a cms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, content-management-system, google-visualization

I have a page which is working perfectly fine as normal, however I need to embed it into a cms. When I do this it renders fine initially within the html editor, however once published does not display some things. Inspecting the published page I get an `Uncaught Type error: Undefined is not a function`. Why would this not be happening when I just load my page singularly.
This is the function that isn't working:

```
    $(function() { //This line is the error
$('#slider').slider({
    disabled: true,
    range: 'min',
    value: 2013,
    min: 1960,
    max: 2013,
    animate: true,

    change: function(event, ui) { 
        $('#header').text('Year: ' + ui.value);

        xA = ui.value;
        //console.log(xA);

        slider2.setState({'highValue': ui.value});
        slider2.draw();

        setChartView();

    }
}); 
});

  <div> 
    <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -50px;">
            <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-style: italic; text-align: center; margin-top:-30px;">Slide to specify a year or press play to animate yearly changes</p>
              <div id="slider" style="width: 400px; margin-left: 28%"></div>
        </p>

  </div>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63j2mwer/) to show how it renders in normal browser. (Note: I have not bothered to format correctly for jsfiddle debugging, just as an example of how it should look. And ignore the positioning, it is set up so it fits correctly in the cms. The slider down the bottom is what I'm having trouble with.)
Edit: I'm using weebly.

**Slider Problem**
Getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null` when the slider is moved.

HTML:

```
      <div> 
    <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -50px;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/rsud8yD.png" id="startSlider" width="40px" height="40px" style="cursor: pointer; text-align: center; position: relative; z-index: 2;"/> 
          <p id ="header" style="text-align: center; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"><strong>Year: 2013</strong></p>
            <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-style: italic; text-align: center; margin-top:-30px;">Slide to specify a year or press play to animate yearly changes</p>
              <div id="slider" style="width: 400px; margin-left: 28%"></div>
        </p>

  </div>
```

JS:

```
    $(function() {
    $('#slider').slider({
        disabled: true,
        range: 'min',
        value: 2013,
        min: 1960,
        max: 2013,
        animate: true,

        change: function(event, ui) {

            $('#header').text('Year: ' + ui.value);

            xA = ui.value;
            //console.log(xA);

            slider2.setState({'highValue': ui.value});
            slider2.draw();

            setChartView();

        }
    }); 
  });
  var tmOt;
  function scrollSlider(){
    var slideValue;

    slideValue = $("#slider").slider("value");
    if (slideValue >=0){
      if (slideValue == 2013){
        slideValue= -1;
      }
      $("#slider").slider("value", slideValue + 1);
      //console.log($("#slider").slider("value"));
      tmOt = setTimeout(scrollSlider, 500);
    }
  }
$('#startSlider').click(function (){ //onclick


   if ( $(this).hasClass('pause') ) {
      // Button is paused change to play
      $(this).attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/rsud8yD.png')

    clearTimeout(tmOt);

   } else {
      // Button is play change to play

      $(this).attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/uEl5R6T.png')

    scrollSlider();

   }
      $(this).toggleClass('pause')
})
    google.visualization.events.addListener(GenderPicker, 'statechange', setChartView);
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(geoChart, 'ready', function () {
        $('#slider').slider('enable');
        setChartView();
    });
```

This slider's value is hooked up to the default google charts slider's top value as this slider is nicer to look at and allows more customization.

Again, this is working fine in a normal browser window and when it is initially being embedded but fumbling when published.

Comment: Have you compared the actual page output to your source code?  For example, your CMS might be changing/rewriting the output.  Another possibility is that your CMS template does not include the reference to the "slider" library / jQuery plugin.  I would View Source in your browser and verify what is actually being emitted.  Also please include which line above is throwing the Undefined error.

Comment: You did not mention your current CMS, but most of the time, this behavior is caused by the fact that the CMS override the `$`. Try wrapping your code in a closure : `(function($){/*Your current code*/})(jQuery)`.

Comment: @RickDailey Yes I have edited so the template includes it. I think it is the cms changing the output/cms overiding the `$`.
I will try @Karl-AndréGagnon method and see if I get anything

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Would I have to put `(function($){/*Your current code*/})(jQuery)` that for everyone of my functions that uses `$`?

Comment: @user3663720 that or change the `$` to `jQuery`...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I have all that working now, except when I try to move my jquery-ui slider I amd getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null` Now I'm not sure what would be causing this.

Comment: Errr well, I don't know why....

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, Worked it out, there was a conflict in the naming of one of my div elements and the cms'